# Reduce memory in android OpenGL camera

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, bitmap

I am using GPUImage library for taking screenshots/effects. However, on my Acer Liquid Express with Gingerbread 2.3 it works only for 1280x720 max. Trying to set 1600x1200 cause **bitmap size exceeds VM budget** and **VM won't let us allocate 7680000 bytes**. Diving into the code I found the following:

```
IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.allocate(mWidth * mHeight);
IntBuffer ibt = IntBuffer.allocate(mWidth * mHeight);

mGL.glReadPixels(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);

// Convert upside down mirror-reversed image to right-side up normal
// image.
for (int i = 0; i < mHeight; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < mWidth; j++) {
ibt.put((mHeight - i - 1) * mWidth + j, ib.get(i * mWidth + j));
}
}
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ibt);
```

As you can see, it creates 2 buffers, 7680000 bytes each (1600x1200*4) and reverse it because of different 0,0 coordinates in OpenGL and Java. What I want is to **remove second buffer** (to save memory) and keep functionality. Is it possible? If I simply remove *ibt* and *for* loops it creates upside down image without OutOfMemory exception. Also, it will be good to save RGB_565 bitmap, but I am not familar with OpenGL absolutely. Please advice.

Comment: Do you really need the alpha channel? A lot of times the pixel format of the default framebuffer does not even have a destination alpha bit-plane. And even when it does, many times it does not need it. You could cut the size down by 1/4 if you eliminate it.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I don't need the alpha channel. Could you modify the source code correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is perfectly possible. If you want to do it on CPU you only need temporary storage to hold one single line of pixels. To flip vertically you swap lines top most–bottom most toward the vertical center using the usual

```
temp = a
a = b
b = temp
```

approach, where a and b are lines from the large buffer. For the horizontal flip you do the very same thing within the line.

Or you don't mess with the buffers at all and use OpenGL to flip the images before hand (render to a FBO with origin at a different corner)

Comment: It would be great if you show how to do that based on my source code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ***partial*** code solution to your problem. I do not usually re-write code when asked, especially in a language I never use like Java, but I was bored.

```
ShortBuffer sb  = ShortBuffer.allocate (mWidth * mHeight); // 2 Bytes per-pixel
ShortBuffer sbt = ShortBuffer.allocate (mWidth * mHeight); // 2 Bytes per-pixel

mGL.glReadPixels (0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, sb);

// Convert upside down mirror-reversed image to right-side up normal
// image.
for (int i = 0; i < mHeight; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < mWidth; j++) {
    sbt.put ((mHeight - i - 1) * mWidth + j, sb.get (i * mWidth + j));
  }
}

sbt.flip (); // Rewind the buffer

mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap (mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
mBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer  (sbt);
```

This will cut the size of both of your buffers in half, but it does not address the issue of flipping the image in-place. If you do that, you can reduce the required storage another 50%. I will leave that to you, datenwolf's answer should give you the necessary info to do that on your own.

Comment: Thank you for help, however your code generates **Buffer not large enough for pixels** exception in last line `mBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer  (sbt);`